# How to create a tableViewcontroller in DetailViewController of SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6, ios7

I am using Xcode5 master detail application template,what i want is to display a `UITableView` in `detailviewcontroller` of `splitviewcontroller`.

I have programmatically created `uitableviewcontroller` by putting the below code in `viewDidLoad`.

```
UITableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView.view];
```

Its working, but how to implement the `UITableViewDatasource` and `delegate` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass `UITableViewController`, implement the `datasource` and the `delegate` there and then instantiate your subclass. The other way is to set your `delegate` and `datasource` of your `tableView` instance to `self` (the class where you are instantiating it) and implement the required methods there.

Comment: is there any other way to do it.....for example using storyboard...can you provide some link

Comment: Yes, you can: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/851_Implementing_UISplitViewController_with_Storyboards.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just select the detail view controller in storyboard and assign it a custom class that is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Maybe you have to first **remove** the controller provided by the template from the storyboard and add a **new** controller of type `UITableViewController`, making sure that the links (segues, delegate relationship etc) are equivalent to those of the original one.